# Как сделать команду в виде диалога? discord python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Допустим, у меня есть команда -reg. Мне нужно, чтобы пользователь дал пароль и логин. Выглядеть это должно как-то так:
(П - пользователь, Б - бот)

```
П: -reg
Б: введите логин
П: Абобус
Б: введите пароль
П: 125kuku
Б: Абобус 125kuku?
П: +
Б: регистрация завершена
```

-reg Абобус 125kuku МНЕ НЕ ПОДХОДИТ, т.к. в полной команде будет несколько аргументов с допустимыми пробелами

Как же это сделать?

Comment: Вы можете посмотреть на опен сурс реализации чат ботов.

Comment: @DaYa ссылка нерабочая

Comment: @DaYa или то не ссылка...

Comment: @DaYa короче я не знаю что такое опен сурс какие-то суслики походу

Comment: Open Source это программное обеспечение с открытым исходным кодом. Заходите на гитхаб, ищите и находите ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: "*т.к. в полной команде будет несколько аргументов с допустимыми пробелами*" — ответ уже дан [**здесь**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1405635/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-discord-py/1405663#1405663)

Comment: @denisnumb, вот надо мной прям издевается эта планета. Я указал в вопросе, что мне нужно, и может я говорю грубо, но это блин не то что я просил

Comment: @Zix хорошо, чем для вас [**вот это**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1361551/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE) не ответ? Большинство вопросов уже заданы и не один раз.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать ожидание сообщения от пользователя, а затем уже сделать что-то?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1361551/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be)

Comment: @denisnumb
Речь о: message = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60) ?